# Insertion Sort - Linked List - Recursive

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have been trying to write a program to sort a linked list using insertion sort and the solutions I have found does this iteratively, how do we write a recursive algorithm?

ps. this is NOT an assignment problem.

Comment: Usually I'd be asking what your question was, or whatever, but seriously just google this there are answers all over, many of them with code.

Comment: If i didnt do that then yeah whatever, but it is what stack overflow is for isnt it. A little unknown link would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
To insert a node n to a list L:
   If L is empty, return n
   Split L into L0 (the head, first item in L) and LR (the rest)
   If n.data < L0.data then insert n at the head of L and return L
   insert n into LR and return L
```